# Finding real roots of polynomial by using fzero

Tags: matlab, root, polynomial-math

I want to find only real roots of the equation which is ;

```
4*sqrt((1-(z^2/f1^2))*(1-z^2))-(2-z^2)^2-(m*z^4*sqrt(1-z^2/f1^2)/ ...
  sqrt(1-((z^2/f1^2)/y^2)))
```

I know that equation includes complex roots, but I do not want to see them. Moreover, my code fails and says that;

> Error using fzero (line 242) Function values at interval endpoints
>   must be finite and real.
>
> Error in scholte (line 21) x=fzero(fun,x0)

Here is my code;

```
rho2 = 1000; %kg/m3    
rho1 = 2700; %kg/m3    
cl2 = 1481; %m/s    
cl1 = 5919; %m/s    
m = rho2/rho1;    
y = cl2/cl1;    
poi = 0.25;

f1 = (sqrt((1-2*poi)/(2*(1-poi))))^-1;

fun = @(z) 4*sqrt((1-(z^2/f1^2))*(1-z^2))-(2-z^2)^2- ...
      (m*z^4*sqrt(1-z^2/f1^2)/sqrt(1-((z^2/f1^2)/y^2)));

x0 = [1 10];

x = fzero(fun, x0)
```

I changed x0 interval many times, but it showed the same error. How can I fix my code?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like `abs` / `real` etc. could help.

Comment: You could try the following: Plot the abs of the function in the interval `[0, 2.5]`. You will see there are possibly the three roots at `{0, ~0.9, ~1.7}`. Then you could use `fminsearch` for `abs(fun(x))` or [newtzero](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6924-newtzero)  from the fileexchange for `f(x)` with the three starting values  `{0, 0.9, 1.7}` and see what the iteration gives.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as Matlab tells you, is that `Function values at interval endpoints must be finite and real`, and in your case they are not real:

```
fun(x0(1))

ans =

  -1.0000 + 0.1454i
```

Your function is probably just too complex for `fzero` to handle. However I am not an expert, lets see if someone with more knowledge than me can point you in the correct direction for solving that equation.

Comment: Thank you Ander. I am wainting for correct direction

Comment: "...just _too complex_." Or maybe that's just an imaginary reason?